# What is the daily email limit in Google Apps Script?

Tags: email, google-apps-script

Can someone tell me if there is a webpage that lists the official Google limit (Quotas) on emails sent from a Google Apps Script?

In testing my little script I got an error:

> Service invoked too many times: email (# 59)

and now I can't send **any more emails**.

The obvious place for this information would be in the [MailApp.sendEmail documentation](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_mailapp.html#sendEmail). But, that does not say anything about a limit.

I found [this discussion on the google forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-script/thread?tid=5f9fff5195885c6d&hl=en) from 2/11/10 where users discuss about a 100 or 500 emails/day limit, with a 24 hour ban, but no one from Google provided an official answer.

Note that this is for Google Apps Script, which is different from the Google App Engine, which does have well published limits.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()`](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_mailapp.html#getRemainingDailyQuota) to get an "estimate" of how many more emails to distinct recipients you can send for the day.

I haven't sent any emails today and the function returned `500`, so that confirms the daily limit suggested by Joseph.

Comment: Now, free account can send 100/day

Answer (score 15):

Note that as of 30th January 2014 the quota is 100 outgoing emails per day:

[image: Screenshot of the Google Apps dashboard showing 100 emails per day]

Check https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard for the latest values as "All quotas are subject to elimination, reduction or change at any time"…

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard
Here you can see every quota ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have reference for this but in my experience I always calculate my minimum loop duration by taking the quota and dividing it by the number of seconds in the specified quota limit.  So for example if I have a quota that says that I can look at a pretty girl only 86400 times a day then I try to make sure I only look at pretty girls once per second.  It's clear to me that Google does not wait for you to reach a daily limit before they act they seem to calculate the rate of change of quota usage and shut you down when you exceed it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "Google Apps Script" you are referring to a Google Apps account, then yes there is at http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852. The limit is 500 external recipients per day.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. I'm talking about logging in using my gmail account, then in spreadsheets.google.com going to Tools->Scripts. They list a limit of 500/day. I'll have to do an experiment, but I think I got cut off much earlier than 500.

Comment: It could be that they have additional rate limiting enabled if your using a script. But that's just a guess.