# Quota Limits on GmailApp.SendEmail on Google Workspace Business Starter Account

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anybody know the quotas limits for running GmailApp.SendEmail send function on the Google Workspace Business Starter account?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the daily email limit in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744520/what-is-the-daily-email-limit-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: It does not because apparently there are certain conditions that are placed on business accounts that reduces the quotas mentioned in this answer but was found in the link shared in the reply by Teo Corona. Specifically,

Note: Additional limits apply for trial accounts. After you convert from a free trial account to a paid subscription, your account limits automatically increase when both of the following are true:

    Your domain has cumulatively paid at least USD $100 (or equivalent).
    At least 60 days have passed since reaching that payment threshold.

Comment: In that case please post an issue at issuetracker.google.com

Comment: There is no clear information about this. If you use MailApp.sendEmail, it would stop at the limit mentioned like 100 recepients per day (You can check using MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() function) . But, I find that sending GmailApp.sendEmail it would still work even after 100 email in a day. As of now I'm guessing that sending using GmailApp would have same limit as using Web Gmail and sending manually too.

Answer (score 0):

You can fecth using

```
getRemainingDailyQuota()
```

All quotas are mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: It does. It seems that from using the script and checking the quota, my limits will not be updated until the conditions are met the are specified in the link. Thank you! However for some reason running that script does not provide me with an accurate count of how much of my quota I have left. It only seems to give me the total available.

Comment: Maybe you have an "alias" (other emails configured) and consuming quota from one email, and fetching quota from another